# Z-index issue with Canvas, Iframe and Div

Tags: html, canvas, z-index

I would like to have the iframe on bottom, canvas in the middle and some div on top.
This is what I have:

```
<canvas id="drawLineCanvas" style="position: absolute; z-index: 0; display: inline;" width="1450" height="1600"></canvas>
<div id="mainwork">
  <iframe name="inlineCommentingFrame" id="inlineCommentingFrame" scrolling="no" class="imageFrame" src="index1.jpg" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  <div name="commentDiv" id="commentDiv" style="margin-left:70%; z-index: 1;"></div>
</div>
```

However, currently the canvas in on top of both iframe and commentDiv div.
I made some changes:

```
<canvas id="drawLineCanvas" style="position: absolute; z-index: -1; display: inline;" width="1450" height="1600"></canvas>
<div id="mainwork">
  <iframe name="inlineCommentingFrame" id="inlineCommentingFrame" scrolling="no" class="imageFrame" style="z-index: -2;" src="index1.jpg" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  <div name="commentDiv" id="commentDiv" style="margin-left:70%; z-index: 1;"></div>
</div>
```

However, now while div is on top of canvas, the iframe is also on top of canvas.

Any tips on on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the layout you want. Try this.

```html
<div name="commentDiv" id="commentDiv" style=" z-index: 1;">this is div</div>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;display:block"></canvas>
<iframe src="demo_iframe.htm" style="height:200px;width:300px;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using position:absolute I can get what I want to happen.

```
<canvas id="drawLineCanvas" style="position: absolute; z-index: 0; display: inline;" width="1450" height="1600"></canvas>
<div id="mainwork">
  <iframe name="inlineCommentingFrame" id="inlineCommentingFrame" scrolling="no" class="imageFrame" style="position: absolute; z-index: -1;" src="index1.jpg" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  <div name="commentDiv" id="commentDiv" style="margin-left:70%; z-index: 1;"></div>
</div>
```